Whatsapp app crashing. Whatsapp WEB
I have an IPhone 13 and I use WhatsApp daily.
A couple of months ago I had an issue where WhatsApp would crash after a couple of minutes. I would be sending a message and it would just close. When I opened it again, if I was halfway through a message it would be as I had never started it. Listening to voice notes it would crash halfway through and I would have to start over. As you can imagine this was really annoying. Trying to fix it I tried the following things:

Shut the phone off and turn it it back on
Delete WhatsApp
Have WhatsApp on the latest version
Have IOS on the latest version
Tried talking to WhatsApp support which is full of useless automated replies

Nothing would seem to work. I took it to Apple and they suggested it to reset the phone. I didn't want to lose my backup and conversations and because the app crashed so often I couldn't create a backup.
Every so often the phone would stop crashing and give just enough time to create a backup in WhatsApp. I took advantage of that opportunity to save and reset the IPhone. When I did that and restore it, Whatsapp was working fine. After that I decided to link it to WhatsApp Web because I find it easier to type on the computer. As soon as it linked the app began crashing again.
As of now I have tried linking in the browser version, app version and even different computers and it doesn't matter as soon as I try to link it to WhatsApp web the app will begin to crash but WhatssApp web will be working fine. I am tired of this as I want to have both options a working WhatsApp on my IPhone and WhatsappWeb.
As of now I am running IOS 18 and the latest version of Whatsapp.
Any help would be much appreciated

Hi I have the same problem started 2 days ago and tried solving as you did but no luck, not sure what I should do?

See the linked question for jailbreak and non-jailbreak options @DigeshUnia
